# the usage of the word 'before' before a temporal noun?

Tags: grammar

In my understanding, usually the word 'before' is used before a temporal phrase - e.g., before I left home. May I confirm if it is also correct to put it before a temporal noun, as with the following sentence?

Before its present layout, the book's design has been changed many times.

Many thanks!!

Comment: The use of *before* is fine. I would suggest changing *has been* to either *was* or *had been*, since (for the purposes of your sentence) the changes are all complete.

Comment: Thanks Davo. And yes, you are right for changing the tense!

Answer (score 1):

The use of *before* is fine. I would suggest changing *has been* to either *was* or *had been*, since (for the purposes of your sentence) the changes are all complete.